# Lightroom colour issue with secondary monitor

Tags: lightroom, display-calibration, monitors

[image]

I have a laptop and I've connected a second monitor to it, I've done some calibration on its menus so that it has the same look as my laptop but when I open lightroom's two monitors mode, you can see that the second monitor image becomes tinted. My laptop, on the left, has a black&white image, but the second monitor on the right is showing some coloration over the image. This also happens with colour images, but a black and white serves better to see this effect.

Does anyone knows why this is happening and how can I correct it?

EDIt:
While opening photoshop with this monitor connected I got this warning message:
[image]

EDIT 2: I recalibrated as Bart suggested and the photoshop warning was gone, but Lightroom stills shows the same behaviour.

Comment: The Photoshop warning + the LR 2nd monitor behaviour indicates something is wrong with the monitor profile. Did you try recalibrating it?

Comment: I just discovered the same problem. Both of my displays are calibrated correctly and individually. (I use xRite Eye-One Match 3.) After using Lightroom, my display 2 had a similar cast to what is shown above. After a restart it is correct again. I don't think it has anything to do with the original ICC profile or how it is made.

Comment: I investigated this further. It turns out it was not Lightroom that caused the problem.  It was Paint Shop Pro X5.  (I was using both.)  I can now reproduce the problem.  With a fresh boot, using Color Management to change the default profile for display 2 to the one used by display 1 causes the same cast, and setting it back restores the correct profile.  The color changes when PSP is started.  After it is closed, Color Management still says the display 2 profile is the default.  Setting it to the display 1 profile then back to the display 2 profile fixes it.  Might try that after LR.

Comment: i have the same problem. Could you find a solution?

Comment: @HansThomassen recalibrating the monitor fixed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After connecting the computer to my tv and back to this monitor the issue was gone. Nothing of what I've tried work and seriously had no clue as to what happened. Sorry I could not provide any good solution if anyone out there eventually will face this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try using a spyder 4 pro or another product with similar capabilities.

Comment: While I think your answer is referring to the correct solution, could you please elaborate a bit on why this will solve the OP's problem?

Comment: Yes please, you see the monitor colour is ok, the pictures look the same when I have them on my monitor 1 or 2. It's just lightroom that is displaying this behaviour.

Comment: Not an expert but the spyder 4 pro has the capability to profile/calibrate two monitors like you are doing. The device takes a measurement based on what it sees on the screen and compares it with it's reference color. The device then creates a hardware lookup table (LUT) that will give you a corrected image.... Unfortunately you could go buy two of the same exact monitors and do a basic calibration and not have an identical image, you need to do a more advanced calibration using a tool like I suggested.

Answer (score -1):

While this is a shot in the dark, I've had problems in the past with software creating unreadable icc profiles because of character encoding problems (I'm looking at you xrite). In my case some software could read the file, some couldn't. Try copying the content of the icc (icm) profile into a plain text editor, saving it, and replacing the original with the new file. This was how I fixed my issue which might be totally different from yours.

Comment: Not sure about the downvote as the message points to a corrupt profile. Recalibrating won't help if the software consistently produces corrupt profiles. One other thought, when calibrating, are you setting the whitepoint to the same temperature for both monitors?

Comment: The profile has now been fixed with what Bart suggested. Before it was corrupted. Everything looks the same in both monitors, just the images inside lightroom change as show above.

Comment: Do the images look correct when viewed with Photoshop in both of the monitors?

Comment: Yes, in photoshop they look the same.

Comment: If you set up your computer to only use the secondary monitor as the main monitor (close the lid) is there still a problem? In other words, in single monitor mode, using your second monitor as the only monitor, do you still have the magenta cast in Lightroom?